# Passing a list of values from Python to the IN clause of an SQL query

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am trying to pass a list like below to a sql query

```
x = ['1000000000164774783','1000000000253252111']
```

I am using **sqlalchemy** and **pyodbc** to connect to sql:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series,DataFrame
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy

cnx=sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://Omnius:MainBrain1@172.31.163.135:1433/Basis?driver=/opt/microsoft/sqlncli/lib64/libsqlncli-11.0.so.1790.0")
```

I tried using various string format functions to be used in the sql query. below is one of them

```
  xx = ', '.join(x)
  sql = "select * from Pretty_Txns where Send_Customer in (%s)" % xx
  df = pd.read_sql(sql,cnx)
```

All of them seem to convert it into a numeric format

```
(1000000000164774783, 1000000000253252111) instead of ('1000000000164774783','1000000000253252111')
```

And hence the query fails as datatype of Send_Customer is **varchar(50)** in SQL

```
 ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]
  [SQL Server]Error converting data type varchar to numeric. (8114) (SQLExecDirectW)') 
 [SQL: 'select * from Pretty_Txns where Send_Customer in (1000000000164774783, 1000000000253252111)']
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As stated in the comment to the other answer, that approach can fail for a variety of reasons. What you really want to do is create an SQL statement with the required number of parameter placeholders and then use the `params=` parameter of `.read_sql_query()` to supply the values:

```python
x = ['1000000000164774783','1000000000253252111']
placeholders = ','.join('?' for i in range(len(x)))  # '?,?'
sql = f"select * from Pretty_Txns where Send_Customer in ({placeholders})"
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, cnx, params=x)
```

Comment: This WORKED! I've been trying to find the solution and was on several Stackoverflow pages, attempting their solutions but to no avail. Thanks @Gord

Answer (score 3):

Here's the SQL query you need

```
sql = f"select * from Pretty_Txns where Send_Customer in {tuple(x)}"
df = pd.read_sql(sql,cnx)
```

Comment: If x contains only one value, `{tuple(x)}` translates to "(my_val, )" and will cause the SQL query to fail

Answer (score 0):

Used the below approach and it worked fine:

```
       sql = "select * from Pretty_Txns where Send_Customer in %s" % str(tuple(x))
      df = pd.read_sql(sql,cnx)
```

Comment: Terrible idea. That's prone to SQL injection and `str` does not necessarily escape the values in the way that SQL expects (e.g. a `unicode` object in Python 2 will output `u'whatever'`).

Comment: Is the accepted answer really any safer to SQL injection attacks?

Comment: @Mr.LanceESloan - Yes, because the string formatting is only inserting the `?,?, …` string which is under the complete control of our code. SQL injection issues arise when dynamic SQL uses *user input* to embed data *values* into the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Making `sqlalchemey, pyodbc` to work with pandas `read_sql()` is a hairy and messy thing. After much frustration and bumping into various solutions and documentation from [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) and [psycopg](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#lists-adaptation), here's the correct (so far) way to do a query with named parameter:

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
# import pyodbc 
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import text # this is crucial

cnx=sqlalchemy.create_engine(...)
x = ['1000000000164774783','1000000000253252111']
sql = "select * from Pretty_Txns where Send_Customer in (:id);" # named parameter
df = pd.read_sql(text(sql), cnx, params={'id':x}) # note how `sql`
                                                   # string is cast with text() 
                                                   # and key-pair value is passed for 
                                                   # named parameter 'id'
df.head()
```

I've made it work with the PostgreSQL database. I hope it wouldn't be too much different for MySQL.