# How can I pass parameters for the IN clause of a SELECT query to retrieve a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: sql, pandas, pyodbc

Trying to pass params to a simple SELECT query :

`query = """SELECT * from tbl_tab where name in {};"""`

I went through this code to manipulate my dataframe and the idea is to be able to pass 1 to n params into my query :

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(conx_string)
t = tuple(["N","M"])
crsr = conn.cursor()
data = crsr.execute(query.format(t))
rows = [list(x) for x in data]
columns = [column[0] for column in crsr.description]
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns)
```

And I got the expected result. However, when passing a single param to t : having `t = tuple(["N"])`

I got the error
 `ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ')'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")`

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the string representation of a tuple to *inject* into your *SQL* statement. It works for `tuple(["N","M"])` because you get `… IN ('N', 'M')`. However, it fails for `tuple(["N"])` because the result is `… IN ('N',)` and the trailing comma is not valid SQL syntax. Consider an approach that avoids *SQL injection* and uses a parameterized query.

First, if you are using pandas with any database other than SQLite you should be using SQLAlchemy. SQLAlchemy will automatically build the required SQL statement when you pass the `select()` object to pandas `.read_sql_query()` method:

```py
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine(
    "mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger^5HHH@mssql_199",
)
tbl_tab = sa.Table("tbl_tab", sa.MetaData(), autoload_with=engine)

# full contents of table:
with engine.begin() as conn:
    print(conn.execute(sa.select(tbl_tab)).fetchall())
    # [(1, 'Alicia'), (2, 'Brandon'), (3, 'Candace')]

# retrieve subset of rows into a DataFrame
name_list = ["Alicia", "Brandon"]
my_select = sa.select(tbl_tab).where(tbl_tab.c.name.in_(name_list))
df = pd.read_sql_query(my_select, engine)
print(df)
"""
   id     name
0   1   Alicia
1   2  Brandon
"""
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Gord for you help. However, what will be the way to avoid SQL injection in my case and continue with the pyodbc solution if still possible pls?

Comment: You would do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42137739/2144390).